# Binding Keys in Vanilla Minecraft 1.9

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, keyboard

I was wondering if you could bind command and actions to certian keys in **Vanilla** Minecraft? It would make life so much easier.

Comment: What type of commands and keys do you want to bind.

Comment: Do you want a command to run when you press a key, or do you want to change your key bindings?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean something like opening inventory with <kbd>I</kbd> rather than <kbd>E</kbd>, it is possible, and is in the keyboard settings.

If you mean something more complex, it is not possible without using mods or external software such as AutoHotkey.

Answer (score -1):

In order to change your keybinds in Minecraft, you first have to open your menu with <kbd>Esc</kbd>, then click the `Options` button. Inside of this menu there is a `Controls` button, click that and now you're free to change your keybinds to whatever you want.